# OpenERP 7: How to view/ download an uploaded file?

Tags: upload, odoo

I have a field to upload a file to my form. Now I want to be able to view it without downloading the file (it's a photo and no editing of the file is required). When I do download the file I would like to have it keep its original name instead of being renamed to a generic name (ex. original_name.* stays original_name.* instead of becoming serial_number_22.*).

I have the following.

In my .py file:

```
'file_upload' : fields.binary('Sales Contract'),
```

In my .xml file:

```
<field name="file_upload"/>
```

With kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at this module **Document Management System**. This helps you in uploading and associating files to individual records. And separately under knowledge menu you can organize, view, share files and folders and sharing via ftp is also an additional option.

I am sorry if your purpose is different. I thought this may help you.

Comment: This is not quite what I am after. I am not looking for an easy way to upload the files, I just want the files I upload using "fields.binary" to keep their original names instead of getting renamed. Is that possible?

Comment: Fields.binary actually stores only the data (refer class binary(_column) in fields.py). Whereas in Document Management module it's handled as a file as it is. It's more like you create a folder, organize files and associate records to the files so that when you navigate to that record you see related files. Finally organize files with document management module. I've used it for the same purpose. Have you tried using the module?

Comment: I tried using the module but if I understand correctly this allows for uploading files through the knowledge tab. I want to be able to upload them from within the module I am creating. Is there a way to make a link to the module upload function in my custom module?

Comment: No, there's a link in every record where you can attach files. Please look adjacent sides of print button you'll find a button "Attachment(s)". Click on that and select Add where you can browse a file and that file will be attached with that particular record in active. You may need to do that by having form view of that record open. Revert for clarifications. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, I found it and it works good. Is there any way to change the name of the file when attaching it? Or should this be done beforehand outside of openERP?

Comment: The attachment record name can be changed at anytime by getting into Knowledge Menu -> Documents. But the file name can't be changed in openerp itself. Still you have an option to download, rename and upload. The advantage is the renamed file still refer to the record that it earlier attached to.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an image, you can use `widget="image"` to view it directly after upload.

Comment: You can right click on the image and save it. At the moment, yes there is no download option.